# ¿Se usa la expresión "hablando del ruin de Roma" en Hispanoamérica?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, expresiones

Hay una expresión que dice:

> Hablando del rey de Roma, por la puerta asoma.

que se usa cuando en una conversación se menciona a alguien, y da la casualidad de que justo en ese momento la persona mencionada hace acto de presencia.

Esta expresión, que originalmente hablaba del "ruin de Roma", proviene según [algunas fuentes](http://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/cual-es-el-origen-de-la-expresion-hablando-del-rey-de-roma/) de la época del [papado de Aviñón](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papado_de_Avi%C3%B1%C3%B3n) en el siglo XIV, durante el cual hubo una escisión en la iglesia, llegando a existir el papa de Roma y el [antipapa](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antipapa) de Aviñón. Al primero se le llegó a considerar como el mismísimo diablo en aquella época, de ahí que algunos le empezaran a llamar "el ruin de Roma". Precisamente, la versión inglesa de este dicho habla del diablo ("speaking of the devil").

Existen referencias a este dicho [recogidas en el CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=ruin%20de%20Roma&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000) desde el siglo XVI. Por ejemplo:

> *El ruin de Roma, en mentándole luego assoma.*
>
> Hernán Núñez, "Refranes o proverbios en romance", c. 1549 (España)

O también:

> *ALONSO: —Aún no ha traído las camizas la lavandera.
>
>   DON PEDRO: —Pues, hideputa, ¡id por ellas!
>
>   ALONSO: —Al ruin de Roma, cuando le nombran, luego asoma; aquí viene ya la lavandera.*
>
> Anónimo, "Diálogos de John Minsheu", 1599 (España)

Sin embargo, las referencias a este dicho (según el CORDE) son en su mayoría de España, apareciendo tan solo una con origen en Perú:

> *—Cuando se mienta al ruin de Roma...
>
>   —Luego asoma— concluyeron todos a una voz [...].*
>
> Clorinda Matto de Turner, "Aves sin nido", 1889 (Perú)

Por tanto, me preguntaba:

- ¿Es conocida esta expresión fuera de España?
- Si no, ¿qué otras expresiones se usan en Hispanoamérica para referirse a la misma situación?

Comment: Nunca la he oído en Colombia con "ruin". Como dice Martin en su respuesta aquí decimos "rey" aunque Roma tenía emperadores/césares y no reyes.

Comment: @DGaleano: Roma tuvo reyes al principio. De Wikipedia:  "Roma tuvo un gobierno monárquico por un período de 244 años, con soberanos inicialmente de origen latino y sabino, y posteriormente etrusco. La tradición cuenta que hubo siete reyes: su fundador Rómulo, Numa Pompilio, Tulio Hostilio, Anco Marcio, Tarquinio Prisco, Servio Tulio y Tarquinio el Soberbio...  Expulsado de la ciudad el último rey etrusco e instaurada una república oligárquica en el 509 a. C.,..."

Answer (score 1):

En la Ciudad de México no es raro escuchar la frase "Hablando del rey de Roma, *y el que se asoma*". Claro está, debe de haber originado durante el Virreinato de la Nueva España.

Answer (score 0):

Soy del sureste de México (Yucatán para ser exacto) y al igual que mencionan arriba, la expresión común a una situación como la que describes es la misma

`Hablando del Rey de Roma, [y que se asoma]`

la parte entre `[]` no siempre se utiliza, de echo se usa cada vez menos por aquí.

Como un punto aparte, en la mayoría de los textos que he leído de origen mexicano, no hay situaciones similares como para hacer referencias a esta frase, y posiblemente a eso se deba a que no aparezca en el CORDE

Answer (score 0):

En Perú siempre he oído la expresión "hablando del rey de Roma, y el "burro" que se asoma".

Answer (score 0):

En el norte de Argentina se repite de manera incompleta (sin el rey), por lo que hasta ahora no había prestado atención a su sinsentido

> *Hablando de Roma ... el burro se asoma*